# How do i show the specified data when i press the specified list?

Tags: android, flutter, listview

so i started to learn flutter and im stuck at my own project, this time i trying to build a contact list app.

```
class MyContacts extends StatelessWidget {

  final name = [
    "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "Udin Sasaki",
    "Eagle Man",
    "Mario Speedwagon",
    "Gail Forcewind",
    "Riqfi Dayat",
    "Fityan fitiw",
    "Awwala khalqyn",
    "lathon",
    "Arifin",
    "SMK Yusuf",
    "Harley",
    "Mom",
    "Brother"
  ];
  final number = [
    "+62 0895643242455",
    "+62 0895062457455",
    "+62 0895603211255",
    "+62 0895345357455",
    "+62 0898764247455",
    "+62 0895676247455",
    "+62 0895602247455",
    "+62 0895602656455",
    "+62 0895602247877",
    "+62 5567567567567",
    "+62 3454564687900",
    "+62 2343245345646",
    "+62 4567686798767",
    "+62 6785634232342"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Contact'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // do something
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: name.length,
        itemBuilder:(context,index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(name[index]),
            subtitle: Text(number[index]),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/avatar-372-456324.png')),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Contact()),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Contact extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Contact'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // do something
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/avatar-372-456324.png', height: 150,),
                SizedBox(height: 100),
                Text("data that stored in the array")
              ],
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

my question is, how do i show the data that i press on the specified contact? like if i press the "Harley" contact, the text on it will show harley by itself. any help would be appreciated,thanks

contact list:

[image: contact list]

result I need:

[image: result i need]

Comment: Can you share UI image its batter to understand

Comment: Do you want to show data of the user with a Dialog or do you want to navigate to another page for this? If you want to use dialog you can use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html or if you want to navigate to another page you can use this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MyContacts, pass the name to Contact class.

```
Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Contact(name:name[index])),
    );
```

In Contact class, declare like this

```
final String name;
Contact({Key key, @required this.name}) : super(key: key);
```

In the body, replace

```
 Text("data that stored in the array")
```

to

```
 Text(name)
```

You can find more info [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#5-navigate-and-pass-data-to-the-detail-screen).

Comment: when i pass the "Contact(name:name[index]))", it shows that the named parameter "name" isnt defined. how could it be?

Comment: have you defined `name` in Contact?

Comment: yep i do i already defined `name` in `Contact` but it shows that it needs to be initialized before used